# The ProxyFactoryFactory was not configured

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate.search, proxyfactory

Considering this example as a base example, I created the application but when I execute this application I am getting the following error.

> The ProxyFactoryFactory was not configured. Initialize 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory configuration section with one of the available NHibernate.ByteCode providers. Example: NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu Example: NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle

The following is the code snippet I am using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.AddAssembly("NHibernate");

        ISessionFactory factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        ISession session = factory.OpenSession();
        ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.Id = "joe_cool";
        newUser.UserName = "Joseph Cool";
        newUser.Password = "abc123";
        newUser.EmailAddress = "joe@cool.com";
        newUser.LastLogon = DateTime.Now;

        // Tell NHibernate that this object should be saved
        session.Save(newUser);

        // commit all of the changes to the DB and close the ISession
        transaction.Commit();
        session.Close();    
    }
}
```

And my `app.config` file looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section
          name="nhibernate"
          type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        />
      </configSections>

      <nhibernate>
        <add
          key="hibernate.connection.provider"
          value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"
        />
        <add
          key="hibernate.dialect"
          value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect"
        />
        <add
          key="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
          value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"
        />
        <add
          key="hibernate.connection.connection_string"
          value="Server=localhost;initial catalog=nhibernate;Integrated Security=SSPI"
        />
        <!--<add value="nhibernate.bytecode.castle.proxyfactoryfactory, nhibernate.bytecode.castle" key="proxyfactory.factory_class" />-->
        <!--<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Linfu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Linfu</property>-->
<!-- I have tried both the lines but still getting the same error -->
      </nhibernate>
    </configuration>
```

I have `LinFu.DynamicProxy.dll` instead of `linfu.dll`. Will it work? If not, then from where do I get this `linfu.dll`? 
Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Probable duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956281/nhibernate-proxyexception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969894/error-using-nhibernate

Comment: There is also a bug with the build target http://blog.frozzn.com/2010/03/nhibernatebytecodecastleproxyfactoryfac.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have NHibernate 2.1 Alpha3, copy `LinFu.DynamicProxy.dll` and `NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll` from `\Required_For_LazyLoading\LinFu` to your bin (or references)

Then your configuration line should work:

```
<add key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu" />
```

As an aside, I prefer the `hibernate-configuration` section block for configuration.

Edit: Here's the relevant sections from my web configuration if you wanted to set up with `hibernate-configuration` instead of key/value pairs.

Also, it's possible to just put the `hibernate-configuration` part in its own file called `hibernate.cfg.xml`. You can then use the `xsd nhibernate-configuration.xsd` that's in the download to validate your configuration.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration"   type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
</configSections>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
        <property name="default_schema">kennelfinder.dbo</property>
        <property name="connection.provider">
            NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
        </property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
            NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu
        </property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">{Your connection string}</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.isolation">ReadCommitted</property>
        <property name="use_proxy_validator">true</property>
        <mapping assembly="KennelFinder"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: could you plese tell me what is the hibernate configuration and from where i will get the above dll's

Comment: You can download NHibernate 2.1 Beta1 from http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=73818&filename=NHibernate-2.1.0.Beta1-bin.zip&a=5370114

Comment: I have downloaded it still the same problem

Comment: Did you copy all dlls from required_bins and the two dlls from Required_For_LazyLoading/LinFu? Did you copy them to your bin directory or add a reference to them so they're automatically copied? Are you still using the key/value approach? (I can try it that way to see if I get your error too)

Comment: yes i downloaded all the dlls and tried both the approches but still the same error i don't know how to uploadf the code files here. else if i have uploded my project for your refrence

Comment: Thanks for your ID i have sent you the mail. i have attached the project as a zip file. please look into the matter

Comment: hey ben you haven't responded to my mail what happened?

Comment: Am looking at it now. Sorry, was out of town.

Comment: Sent you back an updated config that should work for you

Config in web.config not app.config. And, web site seems to work differently with hibernate.cfg.xml than Web App Project, so I removed that and just updated your web.config.

Comment: How can this be that I correctly created my config-file, copied all of the required DLLs, referenced the sharedLibs under the Reference Path section of my project properties and I still get the error about that ProxyFactoryFactory; only, and I mean ONLY when I don't specify Configure("./hibernate.cfg.xml").BuildSessionFactory(), since when I specify path to the config-file, it works fine?

Answer (score 9):

We actually use Castle Proxy and have the following.

```
<property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
```

After that it's just a matter of making sure that ALL of the files in the NHibernate Castle lazy loading directory are in the bin.

`LinFu.DynamicProxy.dll` isn't enough. You also need `NHibernate.ByteCode.Linfu.dll` (and potentially others).

Comment: can you let me know the source from where i should get these dll's

Comment: They are in the NHibernate download.

Comment: To be more specific, the files are in Required_For_LazyLoading folder after you extract the NHibernate download.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
    </configSections>
    <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
        <session-factory>
            <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
            <property name="connection.provider"> NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider </property>
            <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class"> NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu </property>
            <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=(local);database=HelloNHibernate;Integrated Security=SSPI;</property>
            <property name="show_sql">false</property>
            <property name="connection.driver_class"> NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver </property>
            <property name="connection.isolation">ReadCommitted</property>
            <property name="use_proxy_validator">true</property>
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

Copy `LinFu.DynamicProxy.dll` and `NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll` to the NHibernate's folder and add the same DLL files to the project reference.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after publishing my project via Visual Studio 2008's right-click "Publish..." feature, when trying to push our MVC/NHibernate project out to our web server.

It turned out I just needed to set the correct options in the publish dialog. In particular, in the "Copy" section, specify "All files in the source project folder", and then it started working.  "Only files needed to run this application" was not good enough, perhaps Visual Studio was not smart enough to figure out which DLLs were being lazy loaded?

Answer (score -2):

```
rnate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
<property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
```

Comment: No text. Broken Markup. Posted way beyond the answers above. Chapeau